# Pixel Imperfect Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

My layout is not obeying my commands.

I had trouble with a layout so I created a new basic box with sub-boxes to see what's going on, and no matter what I do the two 300px boxes won't fit side-by-side into the 600px box.

Also, when the 2nd 300px box is forced to a 2nd line there's an unexplained margin between it and the box above.

I checked CSS & HTML validators and they presented no errors.

Any insight to the cause of the annoyance would be greatly appreciated.

System:
Chrome: Version 114.0.5735.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon v:4.4.8, Kernel:   5.4.0-150-generic
(Potential) pebkac model: 1969

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>widthtest</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<style>

html, body {
border: 0;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font: normal 16px/16px Arial;}

main {
background: #000;
height: 600px;
margin: 25px;
width: 600px;
}

#left, #right {
display: inline-block;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
}

#left {
background: #cfc;
}

#right {
background: #ccf;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<main>
<div id="left">
</div>
<div id="right">
</div>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the white space. If you remove all white space between the `div`s, you'll get your intended pixel-perfect result.

```css
html, body {
border: 0;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font: normal 16px/16px Arial;}

main {
background: #000;
height: 600px;
margin: 25px;
width: 600px;
}

#left, #right {
display: inline-block;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
}

#left {
background: #cfc;
}

#right {
background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div id="left">

</div><div id="right">

</div>
</main>
```

However, I think a better way to go about this is to use Flexbox.

```css
html, body {
border: 0;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font: normal 16px/16px Arial;}

main {
display: flex; /* <- */
background: #000;
height: 600px;
margin: 25px;
width: 600px;
}

#left, #right {
/* display: inline-block; */ /* <- */
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
}

#left {
background: #cfc;
}

#right {
background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div id="left">
</div>
<div id="right">
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. In my last comment I addressed the HTML manipulation and instead using font-size: 0; as it was the simplest solution I had found. I hadn't seen flex as a mentioned option anywhere and I didn't try that, yet. I'll test with it and see if I get the desired result of block-type objects, in this case testing using 300px boxes, but eventually in a layout for other content. If the block characteristic is not retained then I'll stick with using font-size: 0; in the parent element and then resetting the font to desired size in the child element.

Comment: @w4phle [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) is a powerful layout tool that makes hacks unnecessary. I recommend learning about it because a flexible box layout can be used in many situations on a webpage and be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

2 x 300px elements won't fit into a 600px element.  Try making them 295px each and you should see it work.  Then you can experiment.

[image]

Comment: Except, if I change them to 600px wide each, they fit perfectly with no black showing. So, if one 600px box is permitted "into" a 600px box, then why not 2 x 300px boxes side-by-side?
```
#left, #right {
display: block;
height: 295px;
width: 600px;
}
#left {
background: #cfc;
}
#right {
background: #ccf;
margin: 5px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: If I make them 300px and float them, it's fine, they're both allowed on the same line.
```
#left, #right {
float: left;
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
}
#left {
background: #cfc;
}
#right {
background: #ccf;
margin: 0;
}```

Comment: Then float them. but that isn't what you were trying to do in the original question.

Comment: Correct. I've been using child boxes to 100% fill parent boxes for 20 years and in the last week everything's breaking its layout. I couldn't fix it so that's why I created a simple box page to pare it down to the basics, but I still can't find the problem.

Comment: Additional: Considering the inline-block objects are treated as words, thus the unexpected spacing, the better and simpler fix for me is declaring font-size of 0px in the parent and then resetting the font-size within the child element (300px boxes). I found word-spacing and letter-spacing changes unnecessary; font-size: 0px on the parent element by itself eliminated the extra space and only required altering one CSS rule; much better than manipulating the content elements (div, p, etc.) in the child element (300px boxes). Hope that helps someone else.